# How to solve the performance difference while querying for records when numeric data is strored in varchar columns?

Tags: sql-server, jpa, querydsl

I am trying to query my database which is `MSSQL` with jpa query dsl library (package `com.querydsl.jpa.impl.JPAQuery`) and found a performance problem while running the query. *I am using java api to execute the query dsl predicate*.

My table has a column called `point_id` whose type is `Varchar(20)` and is used to store numeric values ie number values as string.

When I try the query (***which is also done by the query dsl***)

> select
> testperfor0_.serv_code as hm_serv_8_5_,
> testperfor0_.version as version9_5_
> from
> TestPerformanceObject testperfor0_
> where
> (
> testperfor0_.point_id in (
> 1, 2
> );

the performance is very low when compared to the query

> select
> testperfor0_.serv_code as hm_serv_8_5_,
> testperfor0_.version as version9_5_
> from
> TestPerformanceObject testperfor0_
> where
> (
> testperfor0_.point_id in (
> '1,'2'
> );

The difference between the 2nd query and the one done by the dsl is that the data is provided in single quotes. [This](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/obfuscation/numeric-strings) says that there will be a conversion (`to_char()`) while performing the query and this performance problem is also discussed [here](http://venublog.com/2010/04/20/int-and-string-data-comparison-difference-in-performance-because-of-quotes/) .

Is there any solution for this ?

> Edit: The column is of type Varchar(20) because it can also hold
> non-numeric values.

Answer (score 2):

Your real problem actually begins with your topic sentence:

> My table has a column called point_id whose type is Varchar(20) and is used to store numeric values ie number values as string.

If you are trying to store numeric values, then you should be using some kind of number column, *not* a `varchar` or other text column.

That being said, the performance difference appears to be due to an implicit conversion which is happening with this version of your query:

```
where testperfor0_.hm_inv_point_id in (1, 2)
```

If you must stick with your current data model, then you should be comparing `point_id` against text values.  So, from your JPA code make sure that you are binding Java strings to the `IN` clause.

Comment: The bindings are done as string values , but the query generated will not have the binding values in single quotes right?

Comment: If you JPA model has `point_id` as a Java String _and_ you bind string to the `IN` clause, then yes, I would expect the generated SQL query to have string literals in the `IN` clause, with single quotes.

Comment: I was not able to confirm if the bindings are coming in single quotes or not because of the prepared statement. Is there a way to see the full query with the bindings?

Comment: Not easily, but the Hibernate output from above should reflect the actual queries being executed, I think.

Comment: @JITHIN_PATHROSE, you could run a trace (Extended Events or Profiler) to capture the actual `rpc_completed` requests processed by SQL Server. This will show the actual parameter data types specified by the API, which should ideally match the types of the referenced columns.